# Syntax for creating immutable array in Q#

Tags: quantum-computing, q#, qdk

I'm trying to run this example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/language/statements/variabledeclarationsandreassignments.The compiler tells me that syntax for the array declaration *mutable res = new Double[Length(array)];* is deprecated and to "use [x, size = n] to construct an array of x repeated n times".

When I change it to *mutable res = [Double, size = Length(array)];*, it tells me it's an invalid use of a keyword.

How do I declare this mutable array so the compiler accepts it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
mutable res = [0.0, size = Length(array)];
```

The first parameter is the value used to fill the array, and the compiler figures out the type of the array based on the type of that value so you don't need to include it in the declaration explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you

```
let myArray : ImmutableArray<Double> = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]
```